# How to correctly add JQuery in a WP theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, jquery, javascript, customization

I am pretty new in WordPress and I have the following doubt: I have to include **JQuery** into a theme and I am doing in this way:

I create the following function into **functions.php** theme file and I add it as action:

```
function load_java_scripts() {
    // Load FlexSlider JavaScript that handle the SlideShow:
    wp_enqueue_script('jQuery-js', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js', array(), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_java_scripts');
```

So I think that I can add it as some other javascript or CSS local resources but I am not sure about this method because in this case the **jquery.js** is not a local resource but is an online resource (is the same thing?)

And I also have some doubts because searching online I have found some differents method to add JQuery to my theme, like this one: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/

Can you give me some more precise information about how to correctly complete this task?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Why are you including an external copy of jquery? Is the included jquery library in WordPress not suitable for your uses?

Answer (score 6):

When you register/enqueue your other scripts, simply pass jQuery as the third parameter and it will be loaded first and only once, from the local WordPress files:

```
wp_register_script( 'theme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array( 'jquery') );
```

If you only need the jQuery, simply use:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

You can find a list here about the javascript libraries that are included in your default WordPress site:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

Comment: mmm are you meaning that WP automatically load JQuery in some way and that I have not to manually load it but that I can only pass it as dependency of the other JavaScript that require it?

Comment: I mean jQuery is in WordPress by default, located in the wp-includes folder, so you don't need to use an external source to include the javascript file. You can find all of the libraries included in WordPress in the codex, i updated my answer with a link. Also worth to mention, that jQuery is in no-conflict mode, so instead of $(document).ready(function(){... you should start with jQuery(document).ready(function($){...